# Map structures/schema of all database tables from C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following query which i am passing from front end for ex:-

```
CREATE TABLE [" + TableName + "]"
                             + "("
                             + "[Fname] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,"
                             + "[Lname] [varchar](300) NOT NULL,"
                             + "[CODE] [varchar](6) NULL,"
                             + "[TYPE] [varchar](4) NULL,"
                             + "[AMT] [float] NULL"
                             + ") ON [PRIMARY]";
```

what I want to do is if the table doesn't exists in database I want to create it.

But if it exists then I want to compare that tables structure with the query structure and if there is some difference I want to update the database table. But without loosing the data of the table.

And I want to do it for all the tables of a particular database.

Any suggestions from where to start? How to achieve this task? Any ideas?

Help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can do them both manually or using visual studio -

**Manually:** You can start getting the Meta information by using system tables and information_schema by seeing this post here -

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/24343/sql-server-useful-metadata-queries/

You can then collect all the information you need and compare.

This could also be good starting point -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

**Visual Studio** The best I have for now is visual studio. Inside visual studio first create a SQL Server Database Project.

Then, right click on the project and click "Schema Compare". You will be asked to select 2 databases 1. source and 2. destination. The source is the new database and destination should be the old one. After selecting visual studio will compare them and present a screen  to review changes.

Once you review the changes, check the buttons at the top of the screen and you will find necessary button like 'compare' 'update', etc. There are pretty self explanatory, so I think you will understand them.

I think you can find your way from here. This is documented here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435(v=vs.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250(v=vs.100).aspx

**EDIT** I don't have sql server right now, I had my windows crushed, so cannot show you proper screenshot, but this might help -

[image]